# Setting data source and delegate crashes the app for UITableView

Tags: swift, uitableview, delegates, swift2

New here so bear with me... I have a simple View Controller which contains a `UITableView`.  I am not sure whether I should connect the data source and the data controller to the View Controller. Doing so crashes the app, but if I don't do it, I don't see any output in the table view when I run the app. How should this work?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {    
    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 2
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if section == 0 {
            return 1
        }
        else {
            return 2
        }
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        if section == 0 {
            return "One"
        } else {
            return "Two"
        }
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


        let cell: UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell") as! UITableViewCell


        let cellImage: UIImage = UIImage (named: "generic.png")!

        print("cell")

        if indexPath.section == 0 {
            cell.textLabel!.text = "Section 0, Row 0"
            cell.detailTextLabel!.text = "Detail goes here."
            cell.imageView!.image = cellImage
            print("inside cell1")
        }
        else{
            if indexPath.row == 0 {
                cell.textLabel!.text = "Section 1, Row 0"
                cell.detailTextLabel!.text = "Detail goes here."
                cell.imageView!.image = cellImage
                print("inside cell2")
            }
            else {
                cell.textLabel!.text = "Section 1, Row 1"
                cell.detailTextLabel!.text = "Detail goes here."
                cell.imageView!.image = cellImage
                print ("inside cell3")
            }
        }
        return cell
        }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

}
```

Comment: Have you created outlet of tableview? and set `UITableviewDataSource` and `UITableviewDelegate`.

Comment: FYI - Swift 4 is out now. Swift 2 is dead. It's time to update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your view controller needs to conform to `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate` in order to use those methods. Change your class declaration to this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate
```